# erro com windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei um aplicativo, no meu pc roda normalmente, porem no pc do cliente apresenta os seguintes problemas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui a descrição completa:

```
Assinatura do problema:
  Nome do Evento de Problema:   CLR20r3
  Assinatura do Problema 01:    PowerBot.exe
  Assinatura do Problema 02:    1.0.0.0
  Assinatura do Problema 03:    c7a551c5
  Assinatura do Problema 04:    PowerBot
  Assinatura do Problema 05:    1.0.0.0
  Assinatura do Problema 06:    c7a551c5
  Assinatura do Problema 07:    64
  Assinatura do Problema 08:    3b2
  Assinatura do Problema 09:    System.NullReferenceException
  Versão do sistema operacional:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Identificação da Localidade:  1046
  Informações Adicionais 1: 0a9e
  Informações Adicionais 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Informações Adicionais 3: 0a9e
  Informações Adicionais 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

olhando nos logas do windows, encontrei um log que relaciona a uma thread:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os metodos:
esse aki esta em um timer:

```
 private void timerUsoContinuo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread tGetUsoContinuo = new Thread(getUsoContinuo);
        tGetUsoContinuo.Start();
    }



 private void getUsoContinuo()
    {
        if (condição 01){}

        else if (arquivoLido.banco.ToLower().Contains("sistema"))
        {
            GetDadosSistema.getUsoContinuoSistema(arquivoLido);
        }
    }

public static void getUsoContinuoSistema(Dados dados)
    {            
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Contexto(Sistema.ConectionSistema.conexaoSistema(dados.host, dados.banco, dados.usuario, dados.senha)))
            {
                Empresa emp = Services.VendaService.GetEmpresa(dados.cnpj);

                if (emp.status_servvico != 0)
                {
                    if (emp != null)
                    {
                        string command = " SELECT " +
                                " fpc.fpc_pedido AS seq," +
                                " cli.cli_cpf_cnpj AS cpf_cliente," +
                                " cli.cli_nome AS nome_cliente," +
                                " pro.cad_cod_barra AS cod_barras," +
                                " CONCAT(pro.cad_descricao, ' ', pro.cad_apresentacao) AS nome_produto, " +
                                "  fpc.fpc_qtde AS qtde_compra, " +
                                " fpc.fpc_dt_emissao AS data_compra," +
                                " fpc.fpc_dt_termino AS data_prox_compra" +
                                " FROM estfpc fpc" +
                                " INNER JOIN cadcli cli ON cli.cli_codigo = fpc.fpc_cod_cliente" +
                                " INNER JOIN estcad pro ON pro.cad_codigo = fpc_produto" +
                                " WHERE fpc.fpc_dt_emissao >= " + dados.dataPartida.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") +
                                " AND fpc.fpc_fg = " + dados.filial +
                                " AND fpc.fpc_dt_termino IS NOT NULL" +
                                " AND cli.cli_cpf_cnpj != ''" +
                                " AND fpc.fpc_pedido >=" + emp.ult_continuo +
                                " ORDER BY fpc.fpc_pedido" +
                                " LIMIT 100";

                        #region MyRegion
                        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = " + dados.host + "; port = 3306; database = " + dados.banco + "; uid = " + dados.usuario + "; password = " + dados.senha + "; SslMode = none; charset = utf8; Allow Zero Datetime = true; Connection Timeout = 950");

                        conn.Open();
                        string checkuser = command;
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                        MySqlDataReader reader;
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        #endregion

                        List<UsoContinuoAux> lstUsoContinuo = new List<UsoContinuoAux>();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            UsoContinuoAux newUso = new UsoContinuoAux();

                            newUso.seq = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                            newUso.cpf_cliente = reader[1].ToString();
                            newUso.nome_cliente = reader[2].ToString();
                            newUso.cod_barras = reader[3].ToString();
                            newUso.nome_produto = reader[4].ToString();
                            newUso.qtde_compra = Convert.ToInt16(reader[5]);
                            newUso.data_compra = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6]);
                            newUso.data_prox_compra = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[7]);

                            newUso.cnpj_farmacia = dados.cnpj;

                            lstUsoContinuo.Add(newUso);

                        }
                        conn.Close();

                        if (lstUsoContinuo.Count > 0)
                            //Services.VendaService.SalvarUsoContinuo(lstUsoContinuo, dados.cnpj);
                            Services.VendaService.SalvarUsoContinuo(lstUsoContinuo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            GeraLogError.GeraLog("GetDadosSistema", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, erro.Message, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

alguem sabe o q pode estar acontedendo?

Comment: Tá faltando inicializar alguma variável, está ocorrendo a exceção `System.NullReferenceException`. Debugga e informa em qual parte está ocorrendo o erro.

Comment: problema é q na minha maquina, e em outro pc nao ocorre o erro, funciona redondinho.

Comment: Eu chuto que o erro ocorre nesta parte `arquivoLido.banco.ToLower().Contains("sistema")`, pelo nome a variável lê algum arquivo, provavelmente não há este arquivo pra ela ler na maquina que está testando. Porém o correto é você inicializar a variável para que não ocorra mais a exceção.

Comment: coloquei sistema aki, para tirar o nome real, o nome é outro, apesar disso, funciona normalmente no meu pc, tem mais dois pcs q estão ok. Pior q nao tem como debugar la no cliente, muito estranho.

Comment: No método `getUsoContinuo()` está faltando o operador lógico `>;<;==;!=` na validação `if (condição 01){}` isso confere? Ou foi um erro ao passar o código aqui na pergunta? Pois o erro pode estar ali.

Comment: O problema está dentro do método `getUsoContinuo()`, no erro é referenciada uma Thread pois você cria uma Thread no método `timerUsoContinuo_Tick()` que executa o método `getUsoContinuo()`.

Comment: foi erro ao colar, ja encontrei o problema, uma variavel nao instanciada, a variavel sb. Obrigado a todos.